# mongoose Update with $in is not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following mongoose update in my JS:

```
var ids=[1,3];
restid=1;
db.model('rests').update({ _id: restid,'menu.id': {$in: ids}}, {$inc: {'menu.$.soldCounter': 1}}, {multi: true},function(err) {
    if(err)
        console.log("Error while updating sold counters: " + err.message);
});
```

for some reason, the update is being made on a `rest` document with `_id=1`, but only on `menu.1.soldCounter` and not on `menu.3.soldCounter`

I have tested it several times and the conclusion is that only the first ID from the `ids` array will get updated.

Can someone spot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches, which stated in the guide : https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/positional/

Currently there is no way to update all sub document field in single operator. Here is the discussion on the request of this function : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a way to do that:

```
    var indexes = [1,2,3];

    var update = { $inc: {} };
    for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
       update.$inc[`menu.${indexes[i]}.soldCounter`] = 1;

    }
    db.model('rests').update({ _id: rest._id }, update, function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log("Error while updating sold counters: " + err.message);
    });
```

you need to know the indexes you want to update in advanced. then it takes just one call to the DB.